# How to get multiple values from array based on indices in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

We have an array, say:

```
my_arr = [121, 23, 46, 91, 38, 140]
```

Also we have the array of indexes:

```
indxs = [1, 2, 4]
```

I know about `values_at` method, but it doesn't accept arrays, however, it can accept multiple values, proof: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-values_at

Maybe you could give me a clue how to deal with `values_at`. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
We've got 2 answers, so I I did a benchmark (1000 iterations, array.size = 20, indexes.size = 4)

```
                  user     system      total        real
values_at       0.004502   0.000000   0.004502 (  0.004476)
map[i]          0.005878   0.000000   0.005878 (  0.006968)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can splat the array as below:

```
my_arr = [121, 23, 46, 91, 38, 140]
indxs = [1, 2, 4]
my_arr.values_at(*indxs)
# => [23, 46, 38]
```

Answer (score 3):

As alternative:

```
my_arr = [121, 23, 46, 91, 38, 140]
indxs = [1, 2, 4]

indxs.map { |i| my_arr[i] }
#=> [23, 46, 38]
```